# Populating a Column of Cells with Values from Adjacent Cells (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm quite new to VBA and I'm using it to automate a few simple tasks within my job. A small element of this is finding an integer which is always within a set of parentheses in cells from Column B, but the information before the parentheses changes regularly.

I need to get the values of column C to match the number from the parentheses in B. Currently, my code finds this value from the active cell's parentheses, and applies it to the whole column. I think my problem is in the declaration of the variables, but I'm hoping a more seasoned coder can help. Thanks!

```
Sub fillLeads()
'
' fillLeads Macro
    Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    cellValue = Range("B2").Value
    openingParen = InStr(cellValue, "(")
    closingParen = InStr(cellValue, ")")
    enclosedValue = Mid(cellValue, openingParen + 1, closingParen - openingParen - 1)
    For i = Last To 2 Step -1
        Cells(i, "C").Value = enclosedValue
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fillLeads()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, StartPoint As Long, FinishPoint As Long
    Dim SearchValue As String, FinalValue As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow

            SearchValue = .Range("B" & i).Value
            StartPoint = InStr(1, SearchValue, "(") + 1
            FinishPoint = InStr(1, SearchValue, ")") - StartPoint
            FinalValue = Mid(SearchValue, StartPoint, FinishPoint)

            .Cells(i, "C").Value = FinalValue

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that i help.